# Legacy Laptop Install

Tags: installation, usb, windows, laptop

I have an old laptop that runs windows 2000. It has no internet connection, a CD drive (will not read DVD's), and will not boot from USB. Is there a way I can get the full install file onto my USB drive and transfer it to the laptop and do the install from the desktop?

Comment: please ask questions related to ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/about

Answer (score 1):

If it can read a regular cd you could burn super grub2 disk to a cd and boot from the cd. When you boot from the cd it will bring you to a menu. If you arrow down and hit enter on enable extra grub boot functionality it will take you to another menu that shows: enable usb boot *experimental*. If you select that it may take a second but it will send you back to the main menu. Then you can hit detect any operating systems it may take a minute considering the laptop but your bootable usb drive should be detected that way and you can force it to boot that way so you can install a distro of linux on your harddrive :3 I've had to force many computers to boot like that even got a 1998 compaq and a 97 Acer to do that. Good luck!  Link to cd iso: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/